# Adding more tables to an SQL query with a Union

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, union

I am taking 2 columns (PaidGross and PaidDiscount) and putting them in a single column (Amount) for my results. (I am not trying to concatenate. My  result will have ALL records from both columns in a single column)

The basic query is this:

```
SELECT PaidGross AS Amount, BillingID FROM APPaidInvDtl(noLock)

UNION ALL

SELECT PaidDiscount AS Amount, BillingID FROM APPaidInvDtl(noLock)
```

It returns 35706 records and seems to be getting what I want so I think I have that part figured out but...

Here is my expanded query as I am trying to include data from other tables as well:

```
SELECT APPaidInvDtl.PaidGross AS Amount, APPaidInvDtl.BillingID, DocumentLinks.DocIDInternal, DocumentLinks.LinkDocIDInternal
FROM APPaidInvDtl
INNER JOIN DocumentLinks ON APPaidInvDtl.BillingID=DocumentLinks.DocIDInternal

UNION ALL

SELECT APPaidInvDtl.PaidDiscount AS Amount, APPaidInvDtl.BillingID, DocumentLinks.DocIDInternal, DocumentLinks.LinkDocIDInternal
FROM APPaidInvDtl
INNER JOIN DocumentLinks ON APPaidInvDtl.BillingID=DocumentLinks.DocIDInternal
```

I get 102408 records with my expanded query so obviously I am doing something wrong. I believe I need to get exactly the same number of records in both queries to know that I'm getting the right data.

Thank you for any help or ideas on what I should try! Jordan

---

Update on March 16, 2018:

@Smog @shwant00 Yes, you are right. There are multiple documents linked so I am trying restrict it to a certain type of document. The links between the documents are stored in the DocumentLinks table however the Documents table is the one that has the types of documents specified. So I'm having trouble getting the right data at the right time. My latest try gives me the error: "DocumentLinks.LinkDocIDInternal" could not be bound." Here is my latest try:

```
SELECT APPaidInvDtl.PaidGross AS Amount, APPaidInvDtl.BillingID, Invoice.DocIDInternal, Invoice.DocYYMM, Invoice.Docseq, Checkrun.DocIDInternal, Checkrun.DocYYMM, Checkrun.Docseq, DocumentLinks.DocIDInternal, DocumentLinks.LinkDocIDInternal
FROM APPaidInvDtl(nolock)
INNER JOIN Documents Invoice ON APPaidInvDtl.BillingID=Invoice.DocIDInternal
INNER JOIN Documents Checkrun ON DocumentLinks.LinkDocIDInternal=Checkrun.DocIDInternal
INNER JOIN DocumentLinks ON APPaidInvDtl.BillingID=DocumentLinks.DocIDInternal WHERE Checkrun.Doctype=27

UNION ALL

SELECT APPaidInvDtl.PaidDiscount AS Amount, APPaidInvDtl.BillingID, Invoice.DocIDInternal, Invoice.DocYYMM, Invoice.Docseq, Checkrun.DocIDInternal, Checkrun.DocYYMM, Checkrun.Docseq, DocumentLinks.DocIDInternal, DocumentLinks.LinkDocIDInternal
FROM APPaidInvDtl(nolock)
INNER JOIN Documents Invoice ON APPaidInvDtl.BillingID=Invoice.DocIDInternal
INNER JOIN Documents Checkrun ON DocumentLinks.LinkDocIDInternal=Checkrun.DocIDInternal
INNER JOIN DocumentLinks ON APPaidInvDtl.BillingID=DocumentLinks.DocIDInternal WHERE Checkrun.Doctype=27
```

Comment: a  `APPaidInvDtl` row may be related to multiple `DocumentLinks` which would cause for you to get more records in the second query

Comment: Yes, clearly the joins are going to be responsible for the increased row count.

Comment: Digression: Don't use the NOLOCK hint unless there is an absolute need because of locking issues with nested queries or triggers or something. Especially when dealing with monetary amounts, you're going to get bad data if simultaneous updates are happening.

Comment: @Smog @shwant00 Yes, you are right. There are multiple documents linked so I am trying restrict it to a certain type of document. The links between the documents are stored in the `DocumentLinks` table however the `Documents` table is the one that has the types of documents specified. So I'm having trouble getting the right data at the right time. I will add my latest try to the question.

Comment: @user3088736 the error that you're getting is because you're doing the `Checkrun ` Join before than `DocumentLinks ` and you're referencing it so change the order of those joins and try again

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
with #tmp as (
SELECT PaidGross AS Amount, BillingID as BillingID FROM APPaidInvDtl(noLock)
UNION ALL
SELECT PaidDiscount AS Amount, BillingID as BillingID FROM 
APPaidInvDtl(noLock)
)

select t.Amount, t.BillingID, d.DocIDInternal,  d.LinkDocInternal 
from #tmp t 
inner join DocumnetLinks d on d.BillingID = t.BillingID
```

Comment: I'm curious why you name your CTE with the hash character? I'm not sure that changes the number of rows but it's certainly a good way to help OP understand the problem.

Comment: You could further filter the result set or select distinct. I have just always done it that way, force of habit I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that if you run the first select in the union you will get 51204 rows. The increase from 35706 is caused by the join, but the increase from 51204 to 102408 is because you are using union all. Union all don’t filter out duplicate rows. You need to use union only wich will filter out duplicate rows and only returns distinct rows.